# Keeping WebBrowser control's DocumentCompleted event handlers

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling

This morning, being in urgent need of an effective subject code solution, I have had to write a "quick & dirty" custom one:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace MyTestConsole
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser DocumentCompleted event handlers
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// 
    /// Part of code borrowed from
    ///     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3783267/how-to-get-a-delegate-object-from-an-eventinfo
    /// by  
    ///     http://stackoverflow.com/users/259769/enigmativity
    ///     
    /// Needs refactoring, any is very welcome.
    /// 
    /// </remarks>
    public class WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandlersKeeper
    {
        private const string EVENT_NAME = "DocumentCompleted";
        private System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser _webBrowser;
        public WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandlersKeeper(System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser webBrowser)
        {
            _webBrowser = webBrowser; 
        }

        public static EventInfo GetEventInfo(Type controlType, string targetEventName)
        {
            foreach (var eventInfo in controlType.GetEvents())
            {
                if (string.Compare(eventInfo.Name, targetEventName, true) == 0) return eventInfo;
            }
            return null;
        }

        public void AddEventHandler(System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler handler)
        {
            _webBrowser.DocumentCompleted += handler;
        }
        public void AddEventHandlers(params System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler[] handlers)
        {
            handlers.ToList().ForEach(handler => AddEventHandler(handler)); 
        }

        public void RemoveEventHandler(System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler handler)
        {
            int countBefore = this.Count;
            if (countBefore <= 0) throw new InvalidOperationException("WebBrowser instance doesn't have any attached DocumentCompleted event handlers."); 
            _webBrowser.DocumentCompleted -= handler;
            if (countBefore == this.Count) throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("'{0}' is missing in the list of WebBrowser instance's attached DocumentCompleted event handlers", handler.Method.Name)); 
        }

        public void RemoveEventHandlers(params System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler[] handlers)
        {
            handlers.ToList().ForEach(handler => RemoveEventHandler(handler));
        }

        public void RemoveAllEventHandlers()
        {
            if (this.Count <= 0) return;

            var eventInfo = GetEventInfo(typeof(System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser), EVENT_NAME);

            Func<EventInfo, FieldInfo> ei2fi =
            ei => _webBrowser.GetType().GetField(eventInfo.Name,
                BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                BindingFlags.Instance |
                BindingFlags.GetField);

            var fieldInfo = ei2fi(eventInfo);
            var eventHandler = fieldInfo.GetValue(_webBrowser);

            var removeMethodInfo = eventInfo.GetRemoveMethod();
            removeMethodInfo.Invoke(_webBrowser, new object[] { eventHandler });
        }

        public IEnumerable<MethodInfo> EnumerateAddedHandlers()
        {
            var eventInfo = GetEventInfo(typeof(System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser), EVENT_NAME);

            Func<EventInfo, FieldInfo> ei2fi =
            ei => _webBrowser.GetType().GetField(eventInfo.Name,
                BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                BindingFlags.Instance |
                BindingFlags.GetField);

            return  from eventInfo1 in new EventInfo[] { GetEventInfo(typeof(System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser), EVENT_NAME) }
                    let eventFieldInfo = ei2fi(eventInfo1)
                    let eventFieldValue =
                        (System.Delegate)eventFieldInfo.GetValue(_webBrowser)
                    from subscribedDelegate in eventFieldValue.GetInvocationList()
                    select subscribedDelegate.Method;
        }

        public int Count
        {
            get
            {
                try
                {
                    return EnumerateAddedHandlers().Count(); 
                }
                catch { return -1;  }
            }
        }

        #region Testing instrumentation
        public void ListHandlers()
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("\n    === List Event Handlers: count = {0}", this.Count);
            if (this.Count > 0)
            {
                int index = 1; foreach (var h in this.EnumerateAddedHandlers())
                    System.Console.WriteLine("     {0}. {1} in {2}", index++, h.Name, h.ReflectedType.FullName); // .Assembly.GetName().Name); //  .FullyQualifiedName);
            }
            else
                System.Console.WriteLine("    *** Event handlers are missing.");
        }

        public byte RunTest(int testIndex, string testTitle, Action a, int expectedCountTestResult, Type expectedException = null)
        {
            System.Console.Write("\n{0}. '{1}': ", testIndex, testTitle);
            try
            {
                if (_webBrowser.InvokeRequired) _webBrowser.Invoke(a); else a();
                ListHandlers();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("\n    Error = '{0}',\n    ExpectedException = {1}", ex.Message, expectedException != null && ex.GetType() == expectedException);   
            }
            System.Console.WriteLine("\n   *** Test result = {0} ***", (expectedCountTestResult == this.Count).ToString().ToUpper());

            return expectedCountTestResult == this.Count? (byte)1 : (byte)0;
        }
        #endregion
    }

}
```

Here are tests - I have written simple custom test runner as part of this code solution just to have as little as possible bindings to any test frameworks:

```
    partial class Program
    {
        [STAThread] 
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {                
                var k = new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandlersKeeper(new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser());
                byte c = 0;
                c += k.RunTest(1, "test initial count", () => System.Console.WriteLine("Count1 = {0}", k.Count), -1);
                c += k.RunTest(2, "test remove not attached handler from empty handlers list", () => k.RemoveEventHandler(docCompleted2), -1, typeof(InvalidOperationException));
                c += k.RunTest(3, "test add one handler", () => k.AddEventHandler(docCompleted1), 1);                
                c += k.RunTest(4, "test remove not attached handler", () => k.RemoveEventHandler(docCompleted2), 1, typeof(ArgumentException));
                c += k.RunTest(5, "test add two handlers", () => k.AddEventHandlers(docCompleted2, docCompleted3), 3);
                c += k.RunTest(6, "test add already added handler", () => k.AddEventHandler(docCompleted3), 4);
                c += k.RunTest(7, "test add already added handlers", () => k.AddEventHandlers(docCompleted1, docCompleted2, docCompleted3), 7);
                c += k.RunTest(8, "test remove one handler", () => k.RemoveEventHandler(docCompleted3), 6);
                c += k.RunTest(9, "test remove two handlers", () => k.RemoveEventHandlers(docCompleted2, docCompleted3), 4);
                c += k.RunTest(10, "test remove all handlers", () => k.RemoveAllEventHandlers(), -1);
                c += k.RunTest(11, "test remove all handlers when none are attached", () => k.RemoveAllEventHandlers(), -1);

                System.Console.WriteLine("\n\n*** All tests' overall success count == 11 = > {0:U} ***", (c == 11).ToString().ToUpper());

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("Main: Error = '{0}'", ex.Message);
            }
        }


        private static void docCompleted1(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        private static void docCompleted2(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        private static void docCompleted3(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Here are the test results:

> ```
> 1. 'test initial count': Count1 = -1
>
>     === List Event Handlers: count = -1
>     *** Event handlers are missing.
>
>    *** Test result = TRUE ***
>
> 2. 'test remove not attached handler from empty handlers list':
>     Error = 'WebBrowser instance doesn't have any attached DocumentCompleted event handlers.',
>     ExpectedException = True
>
>    *** Test result = TRUE ***
>
> 3. 'test add one handler':
>     === List Event Handlers: count = 1
>      1. docCompleted1 in MyTestConsole.Program
>
>    *** Test result = TRUE ***
>
> 4. 'test remove not attached handler':
>     Error = ''docCompleted2' is missing in the list of WebBrowser instance's attached DocumentCompleted event handlers',
>     ExpectedException = True
>
>    *** Test result = TRUE ***
>
> 5. 'test add two handlers':
>     === List Event Handlers: count = 3
>      1. docCompleted1 in MyTestConsole.Program
>      2. docCompleted2 in MyTestConsole.Program
>      3. docCompleted3 in MyTestConsole.Program
>
>    *** Test result = TRUE ***
>
> 6. 'test add already added handler':
>     === List Event Handlers: count = 4
>      1. docCompleted1 in MyTestConsole.Program
>      2. docCompleted2 in MyTestConsole.Program
>      3. docCompleted3 in MyTestConsole.Program
>      4. docCompleted3 in MyTestConsole.Program
>
>    *** Test result = TRUE ***
>
> 7. 'test add already added handlers':
>     === List Event Handlers: count = 7
>      1. docCompleted1 in MyTestConsole.Program
>      2. docCompleted2 in MyTestConsole.Program
>      3. docCompleted3 in MyTestConsole.Program
>      4. docCompleted3 in MyTestConsole.Program
>      5. docCompleted1 in MyTestConsole.Program
>      6. docCompleted2 in MyTestConsole.Program
>      7. docCompleted3 in MyTestConsole.Program
>
>    *** Test result = TRUE ***
>
> 8. 'test remove one handler':
>     === List Event Handlers: count = 6
>      1. docCompleted1 in MyTestConsole.Program
>      2. docCompleted2 in MyTestConsole.Program
>      3. docCompleted3 in MyTestConsole.Program
>      4. docCompleted3 in MyTestConsole.Program
>      5. docCompleted1 in MyTestConsole.Program
>      6. docCompleted2 in MyTestConsole.Program
>
>    *** Test result = TRUE ***
>
> 9. 'test remove two handlers':
>     === List Event Handlers: count = 4
>      1. docCompleted1 in MyTestConsole.Program
>      2. docCompleted2 in MyTestConsole.Program
>      3. docCompleted3 in MyTestConsole.Program
>      4. docCompleted1 in MyTestConsole.Program
>
>    *** Test result = TRUE ***
>
> 10. 'test remove all handlers':
>     === List Event Handlers: count = -1
>     *** Event handlers are missing.
>
>    *** Test result = TRUE ***
>
> 11. 'test remove all handlers when none are attached':
>     === List Event Handlers: count = -1
>     *** Event handlers are missing.
>
>    *** Test result = TRUE ***
>
>
> *** All tests' overall success count == 11 = > TRUE ***
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> public static EventInfo GetEventInfo(Type controlType, string targetEventName)
> {
>     foreach (var eventInfo in controlType.GetEvents())
>     {
>         if (string.Compare(eventInfo.Name, targetEventName, true) == 0) return eventInfo;
>     }
>     return null;
> }
> ```

a little bit linq with with the help of `FirstOrDefault()` will lead to

```
public static EventInfo GetEventInfo(Type controlType, string targetEventName)
{
    return controlType.GetEvents()
                      .FirstOrDefault(evt => string.Compare(evt.Name, targetEventName, true) == 0);
}
```

> ```
> public void AddEventHandlers(params System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler[] handlers)
> {
>     handlers.ToList().ForEach(handler => AddEventHandler(handler)); 
> }
> ```

Although this looks short and clear, it is creating unneccesary objects by the call to `ToList()`.

```
    public void AddEventHandlers(params System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler[] handlers)
    {
        foreach(var handler in handlers)
        {
            AddEventHandler(handler); 
        }
    }
```

This should be applied for `RemoveEventHandlers` too.

> ```
> public IEnumerable<MethodInfo> EnumerateAddedHandlers()
> {
>     var eventInfo = GetEventInfo(typeof(System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser), EVENT_NAME);
>
>     Func<EventInfo, FieldInfo> ei2fi =
>     ei => _webBrowser.GetType().GetField(eventInfo.Name,
>         BindingFlags.NonPublic |
>         BindingFlags.Instance |
>         BindingFlags.GetField);
>
>     return  from eventInfo1 in new EventInfo[] { GetEventInfo(typeof(System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser), EVENT_NAME) }
>             let eventFieldInfo = ei2fi(eventInfo1)
>             let eventFieldValue =
>                 (System.Delegate)eventFieldInfo.GetValue(_webBrowser)
>             from subscribedDelegate in eventFieldValue.GetInvocationList()
>             select subscribedDelegate.Method;
> }
> ```

there is no need call `GetEventInfo()` twice. Just reuse `eventInfo`.

> ```
> public void RemoveEventHandler(System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler  handler)
> {
>     int countBefore = this.Count;
>     if (countBefore <= 0) throw new InvalidOperationException("WebBrowser instance doesn't have any attached DocumentCompleted event handlers."); 
>     _webBrowser.DocumentCompleted -= handler;
>     if (countBefore == this.Count) throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("'{0}' is missing in the list of WebBrowser instance's attached DocumentCompleted event handlers", handler.Method.Name)); 
> }
> ```

this can throw an `ArgumentException` based on the usage of this class and a registering of the `DocumentCompleted` outside of this class. Assume that from the application somehow a thread comes along registering that event just after `if (countBefore <= 0)`. Then the condition `countBefore == this.Count` will be `true` which results in the said exception.

I think this whole concept how you are doing this registering of events is somehow sub optimal. I don't really get the sense of doing all of this. If you want to be sure that you only register once to that event, you should simply do a `-=` before you add the handler.

If you need to keep track of the amount of handlers registered to the control, why don't you just have a "normal" `Count` property which will be increased and decreased while adding or removing the handler(s).